# Sharepoint 2019: List web part New Item not visible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019, list-webpart

While adding "List Web part" on the home page (or any other page), "New Item" toolbar is not avialble in sharepoint 2019 On-Premise.  How can we achieve this functionality?

The same feature is available for Sharepoint-Online (O365).

Answer (score 0):

The List action toolbar is hidden by default on adding a webpart in SharePoint on prem. Have you tried editing the webpart properties? Its when editing the page then on hover of the list on the webpart top right corner a small button will show up then click on "Edit Web part" it will reload the page with the webpart properties on the right side of the page.

Below find the option where there is a "Show Toolbar" its under 1 of the vertical tabs below, select it and then at the bottom of the webpart properties, click on 'Save' button, after it loads the toolbar with list actions will show.

Hope the concept helps! Happy Learning!

Comment: I can see only "List", "Size", "View" properties when I tried to edit the webpart through "pencil icon".  I am using Sharepoint 2019 On-Prem version

Comment: In that case you might have limited permission to achieve what you're trying to do. May I know what permission you have? You need to have at least 'Edit' permission site collection wide.

Comment: For testing purposes I am using the highest permissions. I mean system admin. and I have "Full Control" for the site.

Comment: Have you tried checking up what options "View" button offers? Given OOTB, it should have that option and as you mentioned you are having a full control permission.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint 2019 and i can reproduce your issue.

The  "New Item" toolbar is only supported in SharePoint online while not supported in SharePoint 2019 currently.

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537